# How to write a list of (string*obj) without using upcast

Tags: f#, dsl

My goal is to write list of name/value pairs in a DSL and make this readable.  The values here can be `int`, `float`, `string` or a list of any of those types.

I am using `string * obj` pairs and passing them to a function that takes a `(string * obj) list`.

Is there to write the list without upcasting the `obj` parameter?.

```
let myfun (values:(string*obj) list) =
    // Do something...

// This is pretty ugly
myfun ["Name", upcast "Freddie"; "Age", upcast 50]

// This would be the ideal
myfun ["Name", "Freddie"; "Age", 50]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Programming 101: if you find yourself repeating the same thing over and over, package it up for reuse, make it a function. In your case, the function would be generic (i.e. take parameter of any type) and do the upcast on the parameter:

```
let pair name value = name, value :> obj
myfun [pair "Name" "Freddie"; pair "Age" 50]
```

Hmm... Not much nicer, is it? But wait, we're not done yet! Now that you have this function, you can give it a nicer name, which would make calling it nicer. Say, `==>`:

```
let (==>) name value = name, value :> obj
myfun ["Name" ==> "Freddie";  "Age" ==> 50]
```

If your set of possible types is known in advance and relatively small (as your question seems to indicate), you can go a step further and have the compiler check that only allowed types are used. To do this, you'll need to use method overloads, statically resolved type constraints and some syntactic trickery:

```
type Casters() =
  static member cast (v: string) = v :> obj
  static member cast (v: float) = v :> obj
  static member cast (v: int) = v :> obj
  static member cast (v: string list) = v :> obj
  static member cast (v: float list) = v :> obj
  static member cast (v: int list) = v :> obj

let inline cast (casters: ^c) (value: ^t) =
    ( (^c or ^t) : (static member cast : ^t -> obj) value)

let inline (==>) name value = name, (cast (Casters()) value)

["Name" ==> "Freddie"; "Age" ==> 50]  // OK
["What?" ==> true]  // Error: "bool" is not an allowed type
```

Comment: Thank you, but your _pair_ function gives me _The static coercion from type     'a     to      'b      involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point_. Are you not seeing the same error? [tryfsharp](http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/seankearon/file3.fsx)

Comment: A mistake. I copied your `upcast` instead of the proper upcast operator with actual type. Corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks, the update you've just made with the Casters() syntax will indeed be useful. I'd upvote you again if I could! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your say that your values can only have certain listed types. I wonder if you have a particular reason to use `obj` instead of a discriminated union, which is perfectly suited for this task?

I've modified Fyodor's answer to use a DU type instead of `obj`:

```
type Value =
    | Int     of int      | Float     of float      | String     of string
    | IntList of int list | FloatList of float list | StringList of string list

type Casters() =
  static member cast v = Int v
  static member cast v = Float v
  static member cast v = String v
  static member cast v = IntList v
  static member cast v = FloatList v
  static member cast v = StringList v

let inline cast (casters: ^c) (value: ^t) =
    ( (^c or ^t) : (static member cast : ^t -> Value) value)

let inline (==>) name value = name, (cast (Casters()) value)

["Name" ==> "Freddie"; "Age" ==> 50]  // OK
["What?" ==> true]  // Error: "bool" is not an allowed type
```

The advantage of this approach is that you now have type-checked pattern matching when you access the values, and you don't have to do unsafe downcasting of the `obj`:

```
let myfun (values:(string*Value) list) =
    values
    |> List.map (fun (k, v) ->
        match v with
        | Int v -> k  + ":" + string v
        | String v -> k + ":" + v.Trim() )
        // etc.
    |> String.concat "\n"

myfun ["Name" ==> "Freddie"; "Age" ==> 50] |> printfn "%s"
//Name:Freddie
//Age:50
```

Comment: Yes, that's a very good point.  I am doing this elsewhere in the program, the question related to code that comprised the DSL.